# How can a printer discovered via NsdManager get added to the PrintService?

Tags: android, printing, nsd

I am trying to implement a PrintService. I am using Network Service Discovery (NSD) to find the printers (c.f. https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html, etc) Both the `NsdManager.DiscoveryListener` and the `NsdManager.ResolveListener` make asynchronous calls. However, the system calls my `onStartPrinterDiscovery()` before the NSD functions are called. I don't see any other opportunity to call `addPrinters()`.

How can this work?

Comment: I think the answer may be to have the DiscoveryListener send a Message to my PrintService. When I get this tested, I'll post it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

onStartPrinterDiscovery() only tells you to start discovery, you need to call addPrinters() every time you discover a new printer (or an existing one has been removed) so you can do that in your listener.

Comment: I suspect that this, with my comment above, is the solution. I'll try it out next week and accept it as appropriate. Thanks for your help